# How can I loop through an If/Then Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have a parent drop down box in Column I and a child drop down box in Column J that changes based on Column I.

If column I changes, I would like column j to reset rather than keep its original value.

I have this code working for my first row

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "I2" Then Range("J2").ClearContents
End Sub
```

How can I get it to loop through every row?

Many Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean whenever a value in I is changed you want the corresponding value in J cleared? Better to restrict to a specific range of I/J - this will do the whole column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.column = 9 Then target.offset(,1).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: I would add that Comintern's solution has the edge on mine in that it will check for multiple cells changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check to see if the `Target` range intersects with column `I`, then loop through all of the cells in the changed range.  You can use the `.Row` property inside the loop to clear the corresponding cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Did something change in column I?
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim test As Range
    'Loop through all of the changed cells.
    For Each test In Target
        'If the cell is in column I... 
        If test.Column = 9 Then
            '...clear column J in that row.
            Me.Cells(test.Row, 10).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```